# Switching monitor of gdm3 from TV to PC monitor (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, login-screen, 22.04

I can't switch my login screen from my tv to the pc monitor. It's also not possible to change plug order as one is Display Port and the TV is HDMI. So, is there any way I can change the monitor on which gdm3 for logging in is displayed?

BTW, theres no xorg.conf and after creating it the nvidia-settings tool still cant write in the data i gave it. Also I think it uses Wayland anyway but I don't know for sure.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, whatever the OS is, the priority order is DVI ➣ HDMI ➣ Display Port; and it is fixed on most of the Displays and Graphics-cards. If you can get to the firmware setting, you can probably change it, otherwise not.